# Can't connect on alfresco's login page but can on /share/page/index

Tags: tomcat, authentication, alfresco

Since 2 days I can't connect to the login page of alfresco.

catalina.out:

```
2015-06-10 15:41:00,089  ERROR [solr.tracker.CoreTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-2] Tracking failed
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(OutputRecord.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(OutputRecord.java:363)
    at         sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:830)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:801)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ByteArrayRequestEntity.writeRequest(ByteArrayRequestEntity.java:90)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.executeMethod(AbstractHttpClient.java:135)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.AbstractHttpClient.sendRemoteRequest(AbstractHttpClient.java:111)
    at org.alfresco.httpclient.HttpClientFactory$HttpsClient.sendRequest(HttpClientFactory.java:371)
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1056)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1897)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1227)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:513)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

It appends the same thing every 15 seconds to the file

And if I try to access /alfresco I get 404

Comment: which version of alfresco you are using?

Comment: The version of alfresco is 4.2.f

Comment: have you uploaded any special kind of file and this happenned?

Comment: Yes I have tried to add the reset password dialog addon (https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/reset-password-dialog) but it wasn't working for my version

Comment: any thing else?any special thing?

Comment: old add on was for old one.I have designed new one by taking reference of old.you can use that. thi is  the link for that https://github.com/krutik-jayswal/alfresco-solutions/tree/master/reset-password-dialog

Comment: Not uploaded but i've created a python script to add password to all the users (Because I've added them from a csv file that wasn't containing there passwords) I was using the python module: pg8000 to connect to my postgresql database and execute a sql command to modify the password. That was the last I did before the login stoped working

Comment: I don't need the addon anymore I have reseted all the users password but thanks

Comment: okay I will look in to this.Previous versions were throwing same error due to the lib of pdfbox inside alfresco/webinf/lib. replace that with new.that may resolve your issue.

Comment: How do I install your reset-password-dialog do I only need to put the three file in the lib folder in my /opt/alfresco-4.2.f/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib and then restart?

Comment: you can put jar file inside tomcat/lib

Comment: I've installed the jar files but it still doesn't works

Comment: have you removed old one?

Comment: You probably need to look in to before this error in your logs. What is the first error in your logs which you encountered.

Comment: Yes i've removed the old jar